# How to declare a function with dynamic arguments in c#

Tags: c#

Is there a way in c# to declare a function that can take a dynamic number of same type arguments without overloading the function like:

```
in foo(...)

foo(1) foo(1, 2) foo(1, 2, 3...)
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit Marc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use params keyword:

```
int foo(params int[] arguments)
{
....
}
```

Comment: Simple and short, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about [params](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

You can specify a method's signature such as:

```
public void Foo(params int[] list)
{
}
```

Where `list` is going to be an array of integers.

Answer (score 0):

Using the ParamArrayAttribute you can get the desired effect.

`Public void Foo(params int[] list){}`

Examples of calling the method:

`Foo(1);`
`Foo(1,2);`
`Foo(1,2,3);`

Please see here for more info on
[Msdn multiple parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms229008(v=vs.100).aspx)